# How to pass this DateRangePicker value into TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 class _LemburFormState extends State<LemburForm> {
  final _fromKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String tanggal;
  DateTimeRange dateRange;

  final List<String> errors = [];

  String getFrom() {
    if (dateRange == null) {
      return 'Hari ini';
    } else {
      return DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(dateRange.start);
    }
  }

  String getUntil() {
    if (dateRange == null) {
      return 'Sampai dengan';
    } else {
      return DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(dateRange.end);
    }
  }
   
  TextFormField buildDateFromField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
      onSaved: (newValue) => tanggal = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kDateNullError);
        }
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kDateNullError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      onTap: () {
        pickDateRange(context);
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Tanggal Lembur",
        hintText: "${getFrom()} - ${getUntil()}",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
      ),
    );
  }

  // Data Range Picker
  Future pickDateRange(BuildContext context) async {
    final initialDateRange = DateTimeRange(
      start: DateTime.now(),
      end: DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 24 * 3)),
    );
    final newDateRange = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 5),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
      initialDateRange: dateRange ?? initialDateRange,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: Colors.teal,
            accentColor: Colors.teal,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.teal),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );

    if (newDateRange == null) return;
    setState(() => dateRange = newDateRange);
  }
}
```

I created a TextFormField, when I click it will display the DateRangePicker.

After selecting the date, and when I try to submit data, validation detects that DateRangePicker value is not entered.

Like the picture below, I try to click the "Buat Pengajuan" button the DateRangePicker value does not enter the TextFormField, maybe someone can help me solve this problem?

[Link my source code](https://github.com/Hafidz2114/App_Absensi_Flutter)

[image: DateRangePicker value not entered]

Comment: Maybe you could change the validator in the buildDateFromField function to test whether dateRange is set.

Answer (score 1):

Use a controller for the textformfield and get the value from the datepicker to the controller.text property

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Refer the link on how to use controllers.

This might help you.

[How to get flutter datepicker value to the textfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528177/how-to-get-flutter-datepicker-value-to-the-textfield)

Comment: maybe you can give an example with my code ?